# Why RedirectToAction after Fetch POST request does not return new View()?

Tags: javascript, fetch, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using **Asp.Net Core 2.2**

I do not understand why, after Fetch POST call, my POST IActionResult does not redirect to another action and its view?

My Fetch in JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
        var requestToken = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value
        fetch('http://localhost:53801/User/Checkout', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                "X-ANTI-FORGERY-TOKEN": requestToken,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                token: 'sometoken',
                payerID: 'someid',
                amount: price,
                users: usersQty,
                years: yearsQty
            })
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`error: ${err}`);
            });
    }
```

My POST Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout([FromBody] TransactionCompletedModel transaction)
        {
            AppUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.PremiumExpiring == null || user.PremiumExpiring < DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    user.PremiumExpiring = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1); //if not yet have full access
                }
                else
                {
                    user.PremiumExpiring = user.PremiumExpiring.AddYears(1); //if already have full access
                }

                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(TransactionCompleted));
        }
```

And method that just supposed to return new View, but it does not:

```
[Authorize]
        public IActionResult TransactionCompleted()
        {

            return View();
        }
```

After executing Fetch call I receive in browsers console:

> XHR GET http://localhost:53801/User/TransactionCompleted [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 724ms]

As I understand, there is nothing wrong with my `RedirectToAction`, so why `public IActionResult TransactionCompleted()` does not return / reload new view, just I stuck with the old view, where Fetch call was executed?

Comment: Sounds as if you're expecting the browser window to be redirected to TransactionCompleted? If yes, ... no, that's not how fetch() works. You'll have to process the result in javascript and do the redirect on client side. Server side RedirectToAction will only work if you start the request from your browser's location bar.

Comment: Do you think, that if I will call from `fetch().then()` a JS function, that calls fetch GET some `IActionResult`, it should do the job? Or how, in the other way I supposed to be redirected after Fetch call?

Comment: your js function does not get IActionResult but http headers. Your redirect is currently INSIDE of your fetch() function. In JavaScript you "redirect" e.g. using `location.href`. If you don't want to hardcode the url, return the url in response f Checkout() action.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I hoped for a bit more elegant solution with Fetch API. Anyway, thank you, you halped me to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After advices from **Christoph Lütjen** I had to modify my controller POST action to return URL:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout([FromBody] TransactionCompletedModel transaction)
        {
            //other rows without change

            return Ok("TransactionCompleted?token=" + transaction.Token);
        }
```

And now my Fetch API call takes response from POST call to `Checkout`, and uses it for redirection:

```
var requestToken = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value
        fetch('http://localhost:53801/User/Checkout', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                "X-ANTI-FORGERY-TOKEN": requestToken,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                token: 'sometoken',
                payerID: 'someid',
                amount: price,
                users: usersQty,
                years: yearsQty
            })
        })
            .then((response) => { return response.json(); })
            .then((result) => { window.location = result })
            .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`error: ${err}`);
            });
```